# $a_{n}=\sqrt[n]{x^n+x^{n-1}+\ldots +x+1}$ prove decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, limits

As in the title, I have to prove that $$a_{n}=\sqrt[n]{x^n+x^{n-1}+\ldots+x+1}$$
is decreasing and it goes to $x$. My attempt was to write it as $$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\sqrt[n+1]{x^{n+1}+a_n^n}-a_{n}$$ however is does not help. I would be very grateful for any suggestion, hints, etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about $x$ ?

Comment: Try considering $a_{n+1}/a_n$ instead of $a_{n+1}-a_n.$

Comment: What assumptions are you making about $x$?

Comment: $$x^{n+1}-1=(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+ \ldots + 1)$$
$$x^{n}+\ldots + 1= \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$ if $x \neq 1$.

Comment: $x>0$ and i know sum of geometric serie, but what it gives us?

Comment: The claim is false. If $x=0$ then $a_n=1$ for all $n$ and converges to $1\ne x$. If $x>0$ then $a_1=1$, $a_2=\sqrt{1+x}>a_1$, hence the sequence is not decreasing.

Comment: Could be. So you suggest using induction to prove that it increases?

Comment: We always have $a_n\ge1$, when $x>0$. Therefore the sequence cannot converge to $x$ unless $x\ge1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>1$, observe that 
$$b_n:=\frac{a_n}x=\sqrt[n]{1+\frac1x+\cdots +\frac1{x^n}}$$
and the radicand converges to $\frac1{1-\frac1x}=\frac x{x-1}>0$, hence $b_n\to 1$ and $a_n\to x$.

If $x=1$ then $a_n=\sqrt[n] n\to1$ is well-known.

If $-1<x<1$, then $$a_n=\sqrt[n]{1+x+\cdots + x^n}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}}\to 1$$
because $\sqrt[n]{1-x}\to 1$ and even more so $\sqrt[n]{1-x^{n+1}}\to 1$ because $1-x^{n+1}\to1$.

In summary:

- $a_n\to x$ if $x\ge 1$
- $a_n\to 1$ if $-1< x\le 1$.

Comment: Yeah, but the task was to prove that is decreases/increases, not to find its limits (however I appreciate that you did this, thanks for it)

Comment: @user46034 One of the tasks was to show "and it goes to $x$" (which it doesn't always do). The other task is to show that it decreases (which it doesn't always do either).

Comment: @Sergei $\lim a_n=1$ if $x=0$.

Comment: Alright, my mistake (you are right). But how to prove decreasing (or increasing) in such a case?

Comment: Same question was asked recently, [please see this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234821/examine-sqrtnxnxn-1-x1)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yep

Comment: Don't you see that it was my question? I repost because noone answered about decreasing or increasing.